# jquery transparent navbar only on first page

Tags: jquery

I've made an jquery script which makes my navbar from `transparent - color` and I wonder if i can make this happen only on the first page.

Also i wanna say that I'm loading my pages from controller with the same header, footer for all of them.

```
var OFFSET_TOP = 50;
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($('.navbar').length) {
    if ($('.navbar').offset().top > OFFSET_TOP) {
      $('.scrolling-navbar').addClass('top-nav-collapse');
    } else {
      $('.scrolling-navbar').removeClass('top-nav-collapse');
    }
  }
});
```

CSS

```
.top-nav-collapse {
  background-color: #23c0e9;
  min-height: 3rem;  
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "only on the first page"? Just the landing page, or just the first time it's loaded, or something else?

Comment: It is impossible to tell from your question how to know if you are on the "first page" or what a controller is, so your question is pretty much impossible to answer in it's current state

Comment: just on the landing page

Answer (score -1):

So, there should be different ways in doing this,

one which I recommend is

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(document).scrollTop()>50) {
            $('.navbar').addClass('shrink');
        }
        else {
            $('.navbar').removeClass('shrink');
        }
    });
```

and My css for the .navbar .shrink was

```
.navbar .shrink { 
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.92);
    height: 50px;
}
```